# "for export" or "to export"?

Tags: prepositions

> The product is eligible for export

or

> The product is eligible to export

Which would be the correct preposition to use?

Answer (score 4):

- eligible for is used before a noun (or noun group).
- eligible to is
  only used before a verb.

*Examples*:

- *Mike is eligible for a promotion*.
- *Mike is eligible to receive a promotion*

As "export" is a noun and a verb, you may use both prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first one is the right usage - "The product is eligible for export".

The usage "eligible to" is really used as "eligible to do something". 
The second form "The product is eligible to export" implies that the product *can* export. Now, the product itself cannot export (itself or something else).

So, the second form can be corrected as, "The manufacturer of the product is eligible to export it".

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/eligible

Comment: Why does ""The product is eligible to export" imply that the product can export? "This sandwich is ready to eat" does not imply that a sandwich can eat.

Comment: I see what you mean @sumelic; however, can you tell me how the following works?  `Acme XYZ is eligible to export.` Here, Acme XYZ can be the name of a company or the brand/model name of a product.  How can we know which one it is?